# Change "Run as Administrator" label

Tags: context-menu

There is "Run as Administator" option in context menu. How can I change that label to something like "Run by Emperor's name"? Ideally I would like to change icon as well.

Comment: IIRC `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*` (in the registry) is where the context menu stuff is located.

Comment: @AndroidDev - You should provide a detailed answer on how the author accomplishes their goal.  The answer should be specific, provide detailed instructions, and be detailed enough that anyone can understand what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In regedit, go to `\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shell\runas`

Insert your label to the “(Default)” value.

You can create new string value "Icon" and set a path to another image instead of standard chess shield.

Just like here:

[image]